# How to open a program in a script and keep running the script?

Tags: python, xampp, os.system

I've been trying to use os.system to open Xampp automatically and then run my script made  with tkinter. But the problem is that the script stops until I close manually the subprocess.

Here an example.

```
import os

direccion = 'C:/xampp/xampp-control.exe'
os.system(direccion)

print("Hello world")
```

The print() is not working, and just starts to run when I close xampp manually.
What can I do to, at the same time is opening xampp, keep running the script?

Answer (score 0):

in python codes executed line by line...

there is two ways to do that:

first and the best way is to wrap the code to a function...

e.g.

```
def opener(direccion: str):
    os.system(direccion)
```

then use `opener function` whenever and wherever you want! (e.g. after or abobe your print statement)

second way is to use `threading` modules...

e.g.

```
import os
import threading
import concurrent.futures

def opener(direccion: str):
        os.system(direccion)

def printer():
    print("Hello World!")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(opener, "C:/xampp/xampp-control.exe")
    f2 = executor.submit(printer)
    print(f1.result())
    print(f2.result())
```

more info about [threading & concurrent.futures modules](https://youtu.be/IEEhzQoKtQU)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution working for me:

```
import os
import subprocess

def SomeFunction():
    subprocess.Popen([myAppWithPath])
    time.sleep(5)
    os.system("taskkill /f /im MyApp.exe")
    ...
    # continue with the script...
```

A bit roughly written but it´s quite easy to figure out (once you know).